# url() does not resolve a relative path to the parent folder on the local computer

Tags: css

My directory structure is as follows:

```
+ CSS
  + fonts
    + palanquin
      - palanquin-thin-webfont.woff
      - palanquin-thin-webfont.woff2
      - ... (other font files)

  + my-exercises
    - magazine-2.html
```

Where the nodes with the `+` sign denote folders and those with a `-` sign denote files.

In `CSS\my-exercises\magazine-2.html`, I have a document level style-sheet (i.e. a `<style>` element) from within which I am trying to load the `palanquin-thin` font from within the folder `CSS\fonts\palanquin\`.

However, the `url()` function silently fails to resolve the path:

```
src: url('../fonts/palanquin/palanquin-thin-webfont.woff')
```

Or basically any relative path where the parent folder (..) is involved.

I have tried moving the font files around and trying different permutations. When I place the fonts *in the same folder as the HTML document* or within any of its subfolders, the `url()` function resolves the fonts correctly. As soon as there is a reference to a parent folder, the relative path is not resolved.

Due to the problem being related to folder hierarchies, it would be of little use to provide a **JS Fiddler** or a **Codepen**, so I request you to please download the [`magazine-2.html`](https://github.com/Sathyaish/Practice/blob/master/CSS/my-exercises/magazine-2.html) file and the [`fonts/palanquin`](https://github.com/Sathyaish/Practice/tree/master/CSS/fonts/palanquin) folder from my github repo and try it on your computer, maintaining the existing folder hierarchy.

I am producing the relevant snippets below.

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Palanquin Thin';
            src: url('../fonts/palanquin/palanquin-thin-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
            url('../fonts/palanquin/palanquin-thin-webfont.woff') format('woff');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        body > h1 {
            font-family: 'Palanquin Thin', 'Courier New';
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>This is the heading</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: try `src: url('../../fonts/palanquin/palanquin-thin-webfont.woff')`

Comment: @לבנימלכה That doesn't make any sense. But I'd tried that too before posting and it had failed.

Comment: From which protocol? Generally browsers won't allow `file://` protocol to lookup before the current document's root.

Comment: @Kaiido I think you are hinting at what might be the problem. I suspected that, too. I am not running a web server yet so no HTTP. This is all `file:///` based protocol.

Comment: @Kaiido Can you point me to where it says that `url()` won't resolve non-HTTP?

Comment: Then yes, no browsers I know of do allow this. FF allows to navigate inward, IIRC Chrome allows only lookup in same folder but anyway, you'd be better to run a localhost. It's not that they don't resolve HTTP, but that they do apply security measures to block the access to user's system. If you were able to make such a request, you could theoratically guess the whole file-system of the computer where the page runs.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you. This is a huge hole that many like me unsuspecting might fall into. It'll be helpful if you could write an answer with a citation from someplace authoritative.

Comment: Unfortunately, this kind of security measure is not tied by specs, implentators are masters, and their policies do change from time to time, so it's hard to make an authoritative answer on this. But I'm sure there are dupes discussing this issue.

Comment: @Kaiido I looked around and couldn't find any dupes. Anyway, could you please post an answer nevertheless. Because I think what you're saying is correct, and it'll help a lot like me. I am sure there'll be others unsuspecting who will follow and fall into this pit assuming what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of security measures browsers do impose to the `file://` protocol.

The rules are different in every browsers, but IIRC none does allow to lookup prior to the document's folder, and hence, you won't be able to load resources that are not descendants of your document's root (i.e `my-exercises` in your case).

Firefox should allow to load resources that are inside this folder, so if you are using FF, you can try to set your `magazine-2.html` directly inside `CSS` folder.

Chrome has stricter rules, but also has an `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag which should leverage those restrictions. Not sure if you'll be able to navigate up though.

And the best being of course to run your own local server.